# Empty pandas dataframe fills with random values, how to make it all NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I am trying to make an empty dataframe with pandas and numpy in python, so a dataframe filled with NaN, but everytime it seems to fill up with values. Why is this happening and how do I make an empty?

This is what I already tried:

```
data_class_b = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=range(len(df)), columns=[0,1])
```

[image: Attempt 1]

```
data_class_b = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((len(df),2)))
```

[image: Attempt 2]

The methods that I used are based on answers of questions about making empty dataframes, in which they state they should work. But I don't get the desired results. So how do I make an empty dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `np.nan`:

```
data_class_b = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(df)), columns=[0,1])
```

But for me this working correct too:

```
data_class_b = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=range(len(df)), columns=[0,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my laptop and now it works, so I still don't know why it was not working before but it works now. Before I posted the question I already restarted the python program, but that didn't do it.